Are vector cone diagrams of angular momenta physically meaningful?
I understand that for a given $\hat J^2/ \hat J_z$ eigenstate, it is impossible to define all three spatial components of the corresponding $\hat J$. This leads me to believe that $\vec J$ as a three-dimensional vector does not have any meaning. However, I come across 'vector cone' diagrams such as the one on angular momentum's Wikipedia page, and these confuse me since they require the knowledge of all three components. The diagrams are also accompanied by the notion that these vectors are precessing, as they do in classical mechanics.
Regarding the precession notion, I have found this post, where the answer talks about the precession of the quantization vector on a Bloch sphere and its rotations in 3D. However, a Bloch sphere is something that is defined only for a two-level system and not for a single $\hat J^2/ \hat J_z$ eigenstate. Moreover, the Bloch sphere represents an abstract space that is used to visualize transitions between the two states, but I cannot see how that maps onto a physical 3D space in which the vector cone diagrams are defined. This makes me conclude that these diagrams are just a visualization tool and not physical. On the other hand, the linked image does inspire some intuition behind why $m_L$ and $m_S$ are not good quantum numbers under LS coupling but $J$ and $m_J$ are. That is, the diagram agrees with what QM predicts along the quantization axis but, on the contrary, also seems to claim knowledge about what is happening in the perpendicular plane.
To sum up, where do these diagrams come from? Are they just a classical analogy used to visualize something quantum mechanical? Or are they directly derived from quantum mechanics?

Meaning can always be found if you appreciate the graphics properly. Linked.

Go to a text that covers the item, mindful it is only a limited pedagogical device.

Thanks for the insights!
